# L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: complex-analysis

<\br>
Hi everyone,

My question is about using l'Hôpital's rule for the residue calculation. My function is $h(z)=\frac{1}{sin(z)}$. It has simple singularities in $z_k=k\pi$

The obvious way to use l'Hôspital is to consider :

$f(z)=1$ & $g(z)=sin(z)$

$Res(\frac{1}{sin(z)},z_k)=\frac{f(z_k)}{g'(z_k)}=\frac{1}{cos(z_k)}=(-1)^k$

But I can also replace $sin(z_k)$ by its Taylor series expansion since it is holomorphic in $z_k$, and consider :

$\frac{1}{sin(z)}=\frac{1}{(z-z_k)(1-\frac{(z-z_k)^2}{3!}+\frac{(z-z_k)^4}{5!}-...)}$

$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{(z-z_k)^2}{3!}+\frac{(z-z_k)^4}{5!}-...}$ & $g(z)=(z-z_k)$

$Res(\frac{1}{sin(z)},z_k)=\frac{f(z_k)}{g'(z_k)}=1$

Thus, I have two different results and can't see which is wrong with the second method (I suppose that the first method is correct??).

Thanks a lot for your help
<\br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this has anything to do with L'Hospital's rule...

Anyway, your Taylor series has the wrong sign "half of the time". You need to write
$$
\sin(z)=\sin(z-k\pi+k\pi)=\sin(z-k\pi)\cos(k\pi)+\cos(z-k\pi)\sin(k\pi)=(-1)^k \sin(z-k\pi)
$$
and *then* expand using the Maclauring series for the sine function.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much !